# What's the font used at the top of google

Tags: fonts

I'm not sure if this is really the right site for this, but what's the font called that's used for the

Web Images Videos Maps News Books Gmail more

at the top of google, it's a pretty standard font I'm just wondering the exact name so I can use it in a photoshop psd.

Thanks

Comment: is this a programming question?

Comment: yeah cause you get the answer from the css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) reports it as *Arial* (with a fall back of any sans serif font).

Comment: just plain old arial? I couldn't seem to get it to match. Hmm, I'll try again though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

According to Chrome element inspector:

`font-family: arial, sans-serif;`
`font-size: 13px;`
`font-weight: bold;`

Answer (score 4):

The CSS says `arial,sans-serif`, so it's either Arial or whatever your browser says is "sans-serif".